# unable to boot Ubuntu from a dual boot with windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

just finished installing (dual boot)Ubuntu on my second partition,the first one containing windows 8.1,the installation went on smoothly until the end.but now the problem is that when i power on my computer there is no option to boot into Ubuntu and windows 8.1 just loads normally..is there something wrong..and can anyone help...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your bios. After installing Ubuntu you need to select Ubuntu in your bios boot menu. The location varies with different bois.

It is in the section that covers uefi and secure boot you will see a menu listing both OS

[image]